# Windows 10 Service Start Error 2 (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, windows-kernel, servicecontroller

I am developing a kernel mode driver for Windows 10 and I am stuck on the service start it always gave me this error:

> "0x2 **The system cannot find the path specified**"

to install it I have tried by the following ways:

1. Using **"sc create svname binpath="pathtodriver" type=kernel"**.
2. Creating a service from my c++ a`` with CreateService API and Kernel Mode flag.

Both return the same error for me, but here's the most stranger thing looks I have a desktop (from I am writing this and I develop my apps, study etc) **in this desktop I can install the driver without any problem using both ways**, Now on **my laptop what I use to test some of my software it installed the first time and after that I couldn't start anymore the driver service**, the path is correct
I have checked it a lot of times and tried almost everything.
Also I have other Kernel Mode driver which loads on both computers anytime without any problem its stranger really i have been trying all...

**What I have tried to solve this problem:**

1. Deleting the service from sc using **"sc delete svname"**.
2. Deleting the service directly from registry.
3. Restoring registry.
4. Repairing windows.
5. Installing almost every Visual C++ Runtimes.
6. Install the driver with another service name, file name and different path.

**Nothing of the list solves my problem.**

**(I am on Test Signing to test my driver without DSE)**

**EDIT: Solved was my DriverEntry it was returning 0x2 cause it was not compatible with all optical devices.**

Comment: `Installing almost every Visual C++ Runtimes` This could be a problem if you installed some wrong or conflicting versions. Try running [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), in case the problem is in user mode `sc screate`.

Comment: @dxiv Well seems its not my lucky day i can't figure the ossue and the visuals runtimes arent causing any problem cause i have tried without him and only with some the latest pack that contains from 2015 to 2019 from ms website and nothing